# Loop through dates in pandas datetime object and compare timedifference

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

Hello I would like to loop through a list of datetimes obtained from an Excel file and check if the timedifference between the current iteration and previous iterations > 10 minutes and if so then the current iteration should be previous iteration + 10 minutes. This is list of dates that I got, and I would like index 4 to be index 3 + 10 minutes instead of NaT ex.

```
0    2014-11-01 00:00:00
1    2014-11-01 00:10:00
2    2014-11-01 00:20:00
3    2014-11-01 00:30:00
4                    NaT
5    2014-11-01 00:50:00
6    2014-11-01 01:00:00
7    2014-11-01 01:10:00
8    2014-11-01 01:20:00
9    2014-11-01 01:30:00
10   2014-11-01 01:40:00
11   2014-11-01 01:50:00
12   2014-11-01 02:00:00
13                   NaT
14   2014-11-01 02:20:00
15   2014-11-01 02:30:00
16   2014-11-01 02:40:00
17   2014-11-01 02:50:00
18   2014-11-01 03:00:00
```

Name: Timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
import datetime

os.chdir('C:\Users\NIK\.spyder2\PythonScripts')
file = 'FilterDataTest.xlsx'

data = pd.read_excel(file, sheetname='Ark1')

dato = data['Timestamp']

for i in range(0,len(dato)):
if dato[i].minute - dato[i-1].minute > 10:
    dato_old = dato[i-1]
    dato[i] = dato_old + minute(10)
```

This is the code that I have made so far, I know that it would not work especially the last part with old value + minute(10) this is only to highlight what I am trying to do.

Comment: Your `dato` is scalar so you cannot address `dato[x]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work using `diff`, `Timedelta` and `indexing`:

```
data.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(data.Timestamp)
timediff = pd.Timedelta(minutes=10) #Specify the ammount of time you want to add
#diff() here returns a series where the value for 
#each row is the difference between this row and the previous row
mask = data.Timestamp.diff() > timediff 

#if there are more than 1 consecutive +10 mins different 
#the latter value will update on the updated previous values  
while mask.any(): 
#The following is just one way for assigning the values which has 
#+10 min difference to the previous value + 10 mins 
    data.loc[mask,'Timestamp'] = (data.iloc[data.loc[mask].index-1].Timestamp + timediff).values
#update the mask
    mask = data.Timestamp.diff() > timediff
```

Comment: Thanks, seems more complicated than i had imagined but cheers

Comment: I have added a few clarifications to my answer, hope they will be useful. If you think about it, my answer is very similar to yours but mine is vectorized. Also, if my answer helped you, you can accept it.

Comment: Yeah sorry i have just been a little busy, but it helped me very much thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.